# Extension of bilinear forms

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Consider $L/K$ a field extension. Consider $V=K^n$ vector space over $K$ and $B:V\otimes_K V\to K$ $K-$linear map.

Now I want to extend the map $B$ by applying $L\otimes_K(-)$ functor to $B$. This gives extension $B:L^n\otimes_L L^n\to L$.

Set $K=R$ real number and $L=C$ complex number. Set $B$ to be standard inner product over $R^n$ which is non degenerate.

Apply $C\otimes_R(-)$ functor, I obtain the extended "inner product" map $B:C^n\otimes C^n\to C$ by $(z_1,\dots, z_n)\otimes(y_1,\dots,y_n)\to\sum_iz_iy_i$. Note this is degenerate "inner product".

$\textbf{Q:}$ There is a canonical non degenerate inner product over $C^n$ which restricts to canoncial non degenerate inner product over $R^n$. How do I obtain the previous non-degenerate inner product here? What is the general recipe to construct the non degenerate inner product extension in $L/K$ setting?

Comment: Why is it degenerate?

Comment: @darijgrinberg Ops, I mean it is not positive definite as quadratic form. Sorry for confusion. In Brian Hall's book, it says there is a natural extension of real inner product to complex inner product. There is indeed one but it is not obtained by this way, I think. I could also define $\sum_i\bar{z}_iy_i$ as well.

Comment: @darijgrinberg It is non degenerate for sure but it is not positive definite.

Comment: Ah. Well, one way I see to extend an $\mathbb{R}$-bilinear form $\beta : V \to V \to \mathbb{R}$ to a $\mathbb{C}$-sesquilinear form $\beta' : V_{\mathbb{C}} \times V_{\mathbb{C}} \to \mathbb{C}$ (where $V_{\mathbb{C}} = \mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} V$) is by setting $\beta'\left(z \otimes v, z' \otimes v'\right) = z\overline{z'} \beta\left(v, v'\right)$. This assumes that the conjugation on $V_{\mathbb{C}}$ is given by $z \otimes v \mapsto \overline{z} \otimes v$. Not sure if Brian Hall is speaking of the same extension.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I guess that is what is assumed in the book for extending the real invariant inner product on lie group level to complexified lie algebra inner product.